# How to prevent WooCommerce composite product from adding same product of different component in Cart

Tags: woocommerce, product, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have configured WooCommerce composite product's component in the following manner ( see below 2 screenshots ).

[image]
[image]

On the front-end side of product single page , I am selecting the same product ( eg : Form D ) from those 2 components ( see below screenshot ).

[image]

Now , when I click on Add to cart button , it is showing a Notice like : only 1 product may allow adding to cart , but also it is adding the same product to the cart ( see below screenshot ).

[image]

Now , to prevent adding same products in the cart , I write following code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter__woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
function filter__woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation ( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ){

    $all_pro_id = array();

    if ( isset( $_POST['wccp_component_selection'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['wccp_component_selection'] ) ) {

        foreach ( $_POST['wccp_component_selection']  as $key => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $all_pro_id[] = $value;
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_pro_id); die;
        if ( count( $all_pro_id ) > count( array_unique( $all_pro_id ) ) ) {
            //echo "yes"; 
            $passed = false;
        }
    
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Still , the code is not working and it is adding the same product to the cart ( see below screenshot ).

[image]